# I need a help to do a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have these three tables below in DB

**Tables**

```
`accounts` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `salt` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `premdays` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `lastday` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `key` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `blocked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'internal usage',
      `warnings` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `page_access` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `page_lastday` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email_new` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email_new_time` int(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `rlname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `created` int(16) DEFAULT NULL,
      `email_code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `next_email` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `premium_points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nickname` char(48) DEFAULT NULL,
      `avatar` char(48) DEFAULT NULL,
      `about_me` text,
      `vip_time` int(15) NOT NULL,
      `event_points` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

`players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `online` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`,`deleted`),
  KEY `account_id` (`account_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `online` (`online`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

`gamecodes` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `gamecode` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `accountname` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `premium_points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `alreadyused` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

This is my .PHP that insert FORM's information into TABLE GAME CODES

```
<?php
        function anti_injection($sql)
        {
            $sql = preg_replace(sql_regcase("/(from|select|insert|delete|where|drop table|show tables|#|\*|--|\\\\)/"),"",$sql);
            $sql = trim($sql);
            $sql = strip_tags($sql);
            $sql = addslashes($sql);
            return $sql;
        }

        $accountorname = anti_injection($_POST['accountorname']);
        $gamecode = $_POST['gamecode'];
        $category = $_POST['category'];
        $premiumpoints = anti_injection($_POST['premiumpoints']);

        switch ($category) {
            case 'accountname':
                $insertquery = "INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) VALUES ('$gamecode','$accountorname',$premiumpoints,'N')";
                break;
            case 'charactername':
                $insertquery = "INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) 
                        SELECT '$gamecode',accounts.name,$premiumpoints,'N' 
                        FROM accounts 
                        JOIN players
                        ON accounts.id = players.account_id 
                        WHERE players.name = '$accountorname'";
                break;
        }

        $result = mysql_query($insertquery);
    ?>
```

The problems are:

1. in *case 'accountname':*, before INSERT it must check if informed account is valid in table ACCOUNTS.
2. in *case 'charactername':*, before INSERT it must check if informed character name is valid in table PLAYERS

**I could not do, can someone help me?**

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: Why are these checks required?

Comment: I'd suggest replacing your `anti_injection` function with [`mysqli::real_escape_string`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: That `anti_injection` is pretty LOLworthy, just use PDO PLEAAAASE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$selectquery = "SELECT * from accounts where accountname='$accountname'";
$selectresult = mysql_query($selectquery);
if (mysql_num_rows($selectresult)) {
    // account exists, now you can do the INSERT
}
```

**NOTICE**!

**The mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.**

Comment: Do you have a tutorial?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function for that purpose like this one:

```
function Validate($table, $name)
{
    if ($res = mysql_query("SELECT Count(*) as isvalid FROM $table WHERE name = '$name'"))
    {
        $isvalid = 0;
        @extract(mysql_fetch_assoc($res));
        if ($isvalid == 0) return false;
        else return true;
    }
}
```

So you call this way:

```
case 'accountname':
    if (Validate("accounts", $accountorname)) { 
        // Do things
    }
case 'charactername':
    if (Validate("players", $accountorname)) { 
        // Do things
    }
```

I didn't tested it and I confess that is not the best approach, but it should do what you want.

By the way, your SQL injection functions have some breach holes. You have to filter **all** your inputs cause user can alter the input data of **any** control in the browser. Consider reviewing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do another query to check before you do this. With this you'll still run the risk of someone deleting the account in between the queries. If that's a concern for you, you should look into [transactions](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-transactions.htm).

```
    $shouldinsert = false;
    switch ($category) {
        case 'accountname':
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as account_count FROM accounts WHERE name = '$accountorname'");
            $shouldinsert = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
            $insertquery = "INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) VALUES ('$gamecode','$accountorname',$premiumpoints,'N')";
            break;
        case 'charactername':
            //I'm not quite sure how to check if a charactername is 'valid' but this should get you started
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) as account_count FROM players WHERE name = '$charactername'");
            $shouldinsert = mysql_num_rows($result) > 0;
            $insertquery = "INSERT INTO gamecodes (gamecode, accountname, premium_points, alreadyused) 
                    SELECT '$gamecode',accounts.name,$premiumpoints,'N' 
                    FROM accounts 
                    JOIN players
                    ON accounts.id = players.account_id 
                    WHERE players.name = '$accountorname'";
            break;
    }
    if($shouldinsert) {
        mysql_query($insertquery);
    }
```